# rawQuery() formatting

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android and SQLite.  Does this query look right?  It works when I do the query on a database manager without the variables and it worked till I added the second variable at the end.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT car FROM cars WHERE color = " + color + " AND equipment = " + equipment + ";", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quotes. Try this query if it works.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT car FROM cars WHERE color = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String.valueOf(color)) + " AND equipment = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String.valueOf(equipment)), null);
```

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Jeez that's confusing.  What is the purpose of the single quotes?  And when do I need a semicolon?  I was going off of an example and they used a semicolon to end it...

    db.rawquery("SELECT * FROM simpletable;", null)

I'm confused.  Either way thanks...you saved me a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: This will blow up when any variable contains a quote.

Comment: @Matt Semicolons are needed only between SQL statements, but you are not allowed to execute more than one anyway.

Comment: @Matt SQLite doesn't handle multiple SQL statements, therefore semicolons are NEVER needed. Single quotes are needed to mark string values as such. To include single quotes (apostrophes), just double them.

Answer (score 1):

To make formatting easier and to avoid SQL injection attacks, you should use parameters for string values:

```java
database.rawQuery("SELECT car FROM cars WHERE color = ? AND equipment = ?",
                  new String[]{ color, equipment });
```